# Mandarin equivalent to 而家做嘢做成點?

Tags: mandarin, cantonese

In Cantonese, you often hear people say this phrase 你而家做嘢做成點.

What would the Mandarin equivalent be for this phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

而家 = 現在

做嘢 = 做事/工作

做成 = 做成/做得

點 = 怎樣

"而家做嘢做成點?" (how is work going?) in Mandarin is "現在工作做得怎樣?"

> 做嘢 or 做事 in Cantonese can mean either 'doing things' or "working a job".
>
> - '做嘢' in '去做嘢' (go do things)  refers to "**do things** / **work on things**"
> - '做嘢' in '而家做嘢做成點' (how's work going now?)  mostly refers to "**work in job**"

*'去做嘢' in Mandarin is '去做事' or '去幹活'*

Comment: thanks so much! you're the best. :) the key part was understanding how to translate 做成點 into mandarin. wasn't sure you could use 做成 in mandarin as well, as it seemed like cantonese slang. thanks again!

Comment: so can you generalize 成點. to 成怎樣? for instance, would it be normal mandarin to translate 跑成點 in cantonese to 跑成怎樣 in mandarin?

Comment: Yes. You can say 跑成怎樣 or 跑得怎樣 in Mandarin , but you cannot replace 跑成點 with 跑得點 in Cantonese